# Is there a way to shorten the following code so I don't have to write it out manually

Tags: python

here is the code the code itself is weird but it is largely because for this project I have to use a specific IDE that is weird. However, it uses the same function it's just often typed a little different. Anyways I currently have it set up where once the block is created it will make the block position equal to the position of the block made before it. I have the position of blocks stored in a list and use it to rewrite the So like snake the game. So is there any way of shortening the code so I would not have to manually write each statement?

```
for block in snakeBody.children:
        #changes position of the first block in snakeBody to be equal to the snake head position that is stored in a list 'snakeList'
        snakeBody.children[0].left = snakeList[0] 
        snakeBody.children[0].top = snakeList[1]
        #Makes it so these lines dont run untill the block is actually created preventing an error
        if app.snakeCount >= 2:
            snakeBody.children[1].left = snakeList[2]
            snakeBody.children[1].top = snakeList[3]
        if app.snakeCount >= 3:
            snakeBody.children[2].left = snakeList[4]
            snakeBody.children[2].top = snakeList[5]
```

Comment: Why isn't `block` used in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Any time you find yourself writing the same code with increasing indexes, it should usually be a loop.

```
for block in snakeBody.children:
    for i in range(app.snakeCount):
        snakeBody.children[i].left = snakeList[i*2]
        snakeBody.children[i].top = snakeList[i*2+1]
```

Comment: Thank you so much I have never used indexes much before so this helps me a lot.